# Qt parsing json using network response binary

Tags: c++, json, qt, binary

Alright, I found something I just don't understand. I am making a request to a web service using QtNetworkManager. For some reason I can't seem to go from the network response to a jsondoc directly, I have to cast it into a string and then BACK into uft8?

```
void WebAPIengine::handleNetworkData(QNetworkReply *networkReply)
{

//No network error
if (!networkReply->error()){

    //Cast to string
    QString strReply = (QString)networkReply->readAll();

    //This works, jsonDoc will have the json response from webpage
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());

    //This doesn't work, networkReply->readAll() is said to return a QByteArray. 
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc2 = QJsonDocument::fromBinaryData(networkReply->readAll());
    QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonDoc.object();
    data = jsonObj;
}
//Network error
else{
    data["Error"] = "WebAPIengine::handleNetworkData()";
}
```

Now I can not understand why jsonDoc is working and jsonDoc2 is not. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you do a `QNetworkReply->readAll()`, the `QNetworkReply` object will be empty. So if you call the `QNetworkReply->readAll()` method again, you will not get anything.

Moreover I don't understand why you are converting the `QByteArray` returned by `QNetworkReply->readAll()` into a `QString` and then converting it back to `QByteArray`(by calling `QString::toUtf8()`) to give it to the `QJsonDocument::fromJson` function.

You can try doing this:

```
QByteArray temp = newReply->readAll();
QJsonDocument  jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(temp); // This should work
```

Also make sure to know what the content of the JSon document is, i.e. if it is a map (`QJsonObject`), array(`QJSonArray`), array of maps or map with an array as value.

Comment: alright, looks like I've a mistake in reading my debugger. That was working all along it looks like I'm not pulling out the information correctly. Going to edit post quiet a bit.

Comment: And nevermind, just ran all the json["xx"].isXXX() and managed to figure out how to read the data back in.

Comment: Ok. Good to know that you fixed it.

Comment: Yea, didn't relize that QJsonObjects could nest. Was trying to read it as an array and was coming up empty every time

Comment: You can do something like:
    if(jsonDoc.object().find("XYZ").value().isArray())
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }